# How to enable Fitness api in Developer console

Tags: google-play-services

I want to develop application for google fit i followed [This Link](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started#step_3_enable_the_fitness_api) they mentioned to activate google fit API under oath and Api section.

But i cannot see anything related to google fit api in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and open up your respective project. Under APIs and AUTH -> APIs you should see a list of the available APIs. Enable the fitness API and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can not see the fitness api in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect to Terra's [API](https://tryterra.co) to access Google's API, amongst every other wearable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).